# How to display website in webview after CSS injection is complete?

Tags: android, css, android-webview

I have successfully injected custom CSS to a website with Javascript in webview. But I want to display the website after the website is fully loaded with the custom CSS file. What code do I need to add to accomplish this? TIA

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers `link` tags support the `onload` event (but I vaguely remember that was not the case with Android Browser, and might also be the case with Android webview, you have to check!), e.g. you could do something like this:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                opacity: 0;
                transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
            }
        </style>
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./path/to/styles.css" onload="load()" onerror="error()" />
    
        <script>
            
            const load = function() {
                console.log('styles successfully loaded');
                if ( document.querySelector('body').style['opacity'] !== 1) {
                    document.querySelector('body').style['opacity'] = 1;
                }
            }
            
            const error = function() {
                console.log('error loading styles');
                if ( document.querySelector('body').style['opacity'] !== 1) {
                    document.querySelector('body').style['opacity'] = 1;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <b>I'm the body</b>
    </body>
</html>
```

in browser that do not support `onload`/`onerror` on `link` tags you can use a variety of hacks like having an element with a class that is only defined in the dynamically loaded stylesheet, then check periodically if that element has the expected style rules, if it has, the css was loaded.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I already found another easier method by using onpagefinished and onpagestarted. Maybe your code will help me another time ;)